# Ввод с клавиатуры списка определенной длины

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как через пробел вводить нужное кол-во значений в список?
Например, в C++ это делается так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    cin >> array[i];
```

А в Python'е я дошел только до этого:

`array = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Но в данном случае нет ограничений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: N = 5

In [2]: arr = list(map(int, input().split()[:N]))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

In [3]: arr
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Если я правильно понял.

Comment: Ооо, благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

Практически аналогично вашему примеру на C++, N - кол-во значений.

```
array = []
for _ in range(N):
    array.append(int(input()))
```

Comment: Если вводить значения через пробел, то выкинет ошибку. А мне нужно именно через пробел)